# Is it possible to select data every fifth record but when records are from last day it would select them all from last day?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to somehow combine those

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Data 
 WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

SELECT * 
  FROM Data 
 WHERE id%5 = 0
```

it should something like

```
select * 
  from data 
 where id%5 = 0 but if NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY select *
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to combine the two conditions with an `OR`, like:

> I want all rows mathing `cond1` OR all rows matching `cond2`

```
SELECT * FROM Data WHERE date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY OR id%5 = 0
```